# WPF: How do I create a button "template" that applies a style & has an image in it?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, styles, controltemplate

There are multiple places in my WPF application where I need a button that looks & feels like a regular button, but:

1. It shows a specific icon on it (defined as `{StaticResource EditIcon}`)
2. It applies a style (defined as `{StaticResource GrayOutButtonStyle}`)

I would prefer to define these attributes in a single location, rather than repeating them each place the button is used.  **What is the appropriate way to do this in XAML?**

--

If it helps, below is what I'm currently doing, but I was told this is wrong:

**Updated: Is this the wrong way? Is there a way to fix this so that it is the "right way"?**

I define the button as a template with the key `EditButton`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="EditButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Button Style="{StaticResource GrayOutButtonStyle}" 
             Command="{TemplateBinding Command}">
        <Image x:Name="editImage" Source="{StaticResource EditIcon}" />
     </Button>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then, I declare a button with the template EditButton each place I want to use it in the application.  I also indicate the Command to invoke here:

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource EditButton}" Command="..." />
```

Is this not right?  What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16539347/760893

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:

Have you considered making a custom control? This way, you can create your own attributes to set the image contained in the button, and don't have to rely on multiple styles.

```
<myControl:MyButton x:Name="oneButton" ImageSource="MyButton.png" />
<myControl:MyButton x:Name="anotherButton" ImageSource="MyOtherButton.png" />

class MyButton {

  private string imageSource;
  public string ImageSource {
    get {
      return this.imageSource;
    }
    set {
      this.imageSource = value;
      //set the image control's source to this.imageSource
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Style which targets all the Button of your app. Do do that, simply create a Style without giving it a Key:

```
<Style TargetType={x:Type Button}>
</Style>
```

Then in the Style, you can add a setter which sets the Template property:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <!-- whatever you want -->
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: How would I use a style to display an image on the button & to say that it should include the GrayOutButtonStyle?

Comment: You can change the ControlTemplate to include an image somewhere in the tree. For example you can use a grid with 2 columns, put the image in the first column, and a ContentPresenter in the second one.