# Auto hover color for buttons based on their Background color

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles

I've googled a lot but I've found nothing about this situation.

I have several flat `Button`s with different `Background` colors, but the hover color is the same for all of them! I want each `Button` has its own hover color based on its background, for example gets a little lighter.

I've tried making custom styles and I reduced the `Opacity` in `IsMouseOver` trigger, but It's not what I want because it also affects the content of the button and not only the background color!

Win32 C# applications have a Flat Appearance property that do the trick automatically. When you choose a color for the `BackColor` and set the button as Flat, it takes care of all states color (Hover color, Disabled color, ...), however I've no idea how to do this in WPF.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
the hover color is the same for all of them!
```

This is probably because in your `Button`'s style, you have **one single** `Background` brush when `IsMouseOver` is `True`.

```
because it also affects the content of the button and not only the background color
```

This is probably because when the panel (likely a `Border`) you are animating is also the parent of the content control(e.g. `ContentPresenter`, `ContentControl`), so the `Opaciy` of this content control is also affected.

To solve these problems, you just need to create some visual elements (e.g. `Rectangles`, `Borders`) at the same level as your content control, and animate them based on which trigger is activated.

Here is a simple example.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FF737B7F"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundVisual" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PressedVisual" Fill="{DynamicResource Button.Pressed.Background}" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisual" Fill="{DynamicResource Button.Disabled.Background}" Opacity="0"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="BackgroundVisual" Value="0.6"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="PressedVisual" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="DisabledVisual" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Here is how the style looks.

[image]

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :

http://learnwpf.com/post/2006/03/06/How-do-I-change-an-items-appearance-on-mouseover-in-WPF.aspx

for Background you can simply set the "Background" property instead of setting the "BitmapEffect" property.

Hope this helps

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your response, but as I described above, what should I set to Background property to make it just lighter?! Mamnun :)

Comment: use <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" /> if you want to use the same lighter colors then use the HexValue: something like <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FAC896"></Setter>
Hope this help,

Comment: So what if my Background is green and I want it to gets lighter when the mouse hovers it? I want a general rule. Your method just works when you want all buttons to have Yellow background on hover event! As I mentioned before, I want the current background color (regardless of its color) just gets a little lighter... if it's Green, so gets LightGreen, if it's Blue, so gets LightBlue...

Comment: Long time ago I did something like this, but not for buttons, Maybe it helps you, I use ResourceDictionary with different x:Key, I search it for you and only found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530184/apply-style-for-buttons-in-all-windows-in-wpf, Note that check answer commited by "Sonhja" Hope this help, otherwise I think I'm not the right person to answer this question

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and attention. I've just checked it out, unfortunately it was not exactly what I'm looking for. Anyway I really appreciate your concern and your helpfulness...