# Each dictionary entry must have an associated key error message

Tags: wpf, app.xaml

could someone please help me to solve this problem, I think I have coded right the key required. This is a Style application dictionary test with just one Button.  There are two error messages: Each dictionary entry must have an associated key, and All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them. Line 13 Position 14, both for MainWIndow.xaml.

There are no more code written by programmer in this project.

This is the MainWindow.xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="App.xaml" /> This is the offending line
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource algo}" />
</Grid>
```

And this is the App.xaml code:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="algo" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Offending line should be inside a `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`.Otherwise it will be treated an an entry inside the dictionary. [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Funk, thank you Mathew Jibin, your explanations lead me to find what I think is the solution, it is as follows:

Modified App.xaml to be like this:

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
```

And modified MainWindow deleting everything in Grid:

```
    ...  
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Now, everytime I create a new button it has the desired Style.  Please let me know if you see any possible problem with this solution.  Thanks.

Comment: That's right, if you want all instances of a `Control` to be affected then an implicit Style (like yours) is the way to go. Otherwise you would give the Style a `Key` and reference it in the `Control`.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, the syntax to reference a `ResourceDictionary` is

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="myresourcedictionary.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Direct content of `ResourceDictionary` is considered to be the dictionary's entries. This is where the missing `Key` error refers to. A dictionary should have look up Keys for all its entries:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <conv:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
        <conv:BoolToCollapsedConverter  x:Key="BoolToCollapsedConverter" />
        ...
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

An exception to the rule are [implicit Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035878/implicit-styles-in-application-resources-vs-window-resources) (Styles that have a `TargetType` instead of a `Key`).

In your case none of the above will help, since `Resources` in *App.xaml* are treated special. They're considered *Global Resources* and can be referenced from everywhere. Trying to do reference them explicitly as in the first example will result in

> An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "App.xaml".

Instead change your *MainWindow.xaml* to

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    ...
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource algo}" />
</Grid>
```